# Executing Workable packets in mutiple threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I am new to Multi threading concept of C#/.Net and I have the following requirement.

Our application should first fetch the customers (only ids) for whom data processing needs to be done and based on size of the WorkPacket(terminology used for packeting a set of customers into a workable packet), WorkPackets are created. So each workpacket contains a set of customers

Now each of the workpacket created on run time needs to be executed on different threads. So all the threads needs to be created and aborted on runtime. As the number of customer which needs to processed are very huge we are going with multi-threading concept.

We have working functionality with single thread, but sure how this can be implemented using. Below is the code used. Any suggestions???

```
public class WorkAllocator
{
    private int workPacketSize;
    private List<WorkPacket> workPackets;
    public List<WorkPacket> WorkPackets
    {
        get { return workPackets; }
        set { workPackets = value; }
    }

    public int WorkPacketSize
    {
        get { return workPacketSize; }
        set { workPacketSize = value; }
    }

    public WorkAllocator(int size)
    {
        workPacketSize = size;
        int noOfPackets=0;
        DataManager objDAL = new DataManager(ConnectionString);

        IEnumerable<string> CustomerIds = objDAL.GetData();
        workPackets = new List<WorkPacket>();

        if (CustomerIds.Count() > 0)
        {
            noOfPackets = CustomerIds.Count() / workPacketSize;
            if (CustomerIds.Count() % workPacketSize != 0)
            {
                noOfPackets++;
            }

            var wps = CustomerIds
                .Select((c, i) => new { Index = i, Value = c })
                .GroupBy(c => c.Index / workPacketSize)
                .Select(c => c.Select(v => v.Value).ToList())
                .ToList();

            foreach (List<string> wp in wps)
            {
                workPackets.Add(new WorkPacket(wp));
            }
        }
        objDAL.Dispose();
    }
}

public class WorkPacket
{
    private List<string> customerIds;

    public List<string> customerIds
    {
        get { return customerIds; }
        set { customerIds = value; }
    }

    public WorkPacket(List<string> Cids)
    {
        customerIds = Cids;
    }
}
```

Code on Main method

```
wa = new WorkAllocator(10);
if (wa.WorkPackets != null && wa.WorkPackets.Count > 0)
{
    //Dynamically Create threads for each work packets and join after all child thread completes the activity
    foreach (WorkPacket wp in wa.WorkPackets)
    {
            var _processor = new Processor();
        Processor.Run(wp);
    }
}
```

Comment: some random thoughts on the code: the for the `noOfPackets` better use `Math.Ceiling`. The step with "Select+Index->GroupBy" is easier if you add the "group-number" instead of the index directly (do the `/` right there) or as your foreach anyway: loop your ids once and yield the groups (easier even if imperative). Aside from this I cannot see anything on the way you are doing your parallel stuff - I  hope you are using the ThreadPool in some way ...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a CodeReview

Comment: Carsten - I have added code just for more information. What I actually need is each work packet needs to be executed on a separate thread. Instead in the given code each customer is processed in the for loop so there is no parallel stuff here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution using [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx)s:

```
wa = new WorkAllocator(10);
if (wa.WorkPackets != null && wa.WorkPackets.Count > 0)
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach (WorkPacket wp in wa.WorkPackets)
    {
        tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Processor.Run(wp);
            });
    }

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
```

This will run each `Processor` in its own thread (parallelization managed by the `ThreadPool`) and then wait for all of them to finish.

Maybe also look into [`ActionBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684(v=vs.110).aspx), there you could do something like:

```
var threadCount = Environment.ProcessorCount;
var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<WorkPacket>(() => Processor.Run(wp),
   // this is optional, but default is 1:
   new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = threadCount });

wa = new WorkAllocator(10);
if (wa.WorkPackets != null && wa.WorkPackets.Count > 0)
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach (WorkPacket wp in wa.WorkPackets)
        actionBlock.Post(wp);

    actionBlock.Complete();
    actionBlock.Completion.Wait();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your main method you can simply use [Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v=vs.110).aspx). This is blocking - won't return till all workpackets are processed.

```
Parallel.ForEach(wa.WorkPackets, wp => Processor.Run(wp));
```